# Combo Box Item Won't Equal Constructor c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have the following code:

```
foreach (TrainerFileHandler trainer in mTrainers)
    {

        if (cboTrainer.SelectedItem == (trainer.First + " " + trainer.Last))
        {
            trainerID = trainer.ID;
            break;
        }
    }
```

TrainerFileHandler is my constructor, which has properties of First, Last and ID. Now, I have stepped through the code and seen my selected item in my combo box equal exactly to what the first + " " + last is, but it still says they don't equal each other.

I have something else very similar:

```
foreach (ExerciseFileHandler exercise in mExercise)
    {
        if (cboExercise.SelectedItem == exercise.PlanName)
        {
            planID = exercise.ID;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now that one works perfectly fine. I tried doing like:

```
foreach (TrainerFileHandler trainer in mTrainers)
    {
        string first = trainer.First;
        string last = trainer.Last;
        string full = first + " " + last;

        if (cboTrainer.SelectedItem == last)
        {
            trainerID = trainer.ID;
            break;
        }
    }
```

But that didn't work either. Anyone know why this isn't working? It might help to note that under both of the if statements, even though one works and one doesn't, it says "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'". I tried casting the left side as a string, but didn't help.

Comment: For good measure you should use `String.Equals()` instead of `==`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you fully understand the concept of Constructor. It's that special function you call with "new". `TrainerFileHandler` like you use it is a class.

Comment: @MPelletier: Why? `==` is translated to `.Equals()` behind the scenes already.

Comment: Show us the class definition for `TrainerFileHandler`?

Comment: @Jeroen Just clarity of intent. We don't know from face value what type `SelectedItem` is. Could be a string, could be something else.

Comment: If it is a different type then that means there is something wrong and the code shouldn't be working alltogether. All you'd do by using `Equals` is introduce logical errors when they should be compile time errors. Unless you're using `dynamic`, you should know the type of every variable at every point in the program.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Why was this put on hold? It has valid code and `TrainerFileHandler` has not much to do with it.

Comment: I'll put my answer as a comment for now. `SelectedItem` is a property of type `Object`. You need to cast it to a valid string, depending on what is in the list of items, you can try: `if (cboTrainer.SelectedItem.ToString() == (trainer.First + " " + trainer.Last))`

Comment: Which is why `String.Equals` works because it operates on the basis of strings, whereas `==` operates on the basis of objects of possibly different types.

Comment: @MPelletier: it's the other way around. If you compare your `string` with an `object` that happens to be a string, it will work as expected. If you compare your `string` with an object that is not a `string`, it will still work but not as expected. If your compare with `==` instead, it will never work and basically forces you to cast it to a `string` first, which is compiletime checked.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The asker's `TrainerFileHandler` class isn't at cause here. Question is valid, not off topic, and contains all required code to reproduce, expected and obtained result.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: A downcast is not a compile-time check.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You're right, my mistake. Appearantly it only shows a warning when comparing a downcasted object to an object of an unrelated type. Point still stands though: don't work with `object`, work with actual types.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Working with actual types is definitely better, especially if using `==`, since the compiler can perform a reference comparison instead of a string comparison (such as it would with `object == string`). Hence why `String.Equals` worked. `String.Equals` is NOT the same as `==`.

Answer (score 1):

@MPelletier provided the correct answer as a comment

I needed to use String.Equals() instead of ==.

Comment: Uh, so do I vote this up or...? This is the first time I get the answer in a comment...

Comment: @MPelletier lol. You can put it as an answer and I'll remove mine and select yours as the answer

Comment: Nope, can't. Question's closed. It's alright, doesn't matter.

Comment: @MPelletier  ah. I see. What makes you think I don't understand a constructor? I mean, I use them, I wouldn't say I fully understand them, but not sure how you could tell that from my post.

Comment: I have serious doubts that this is the answer and not something that masked the actual problem. `ComboBox.SelectedItem` returns a variable of type `object`. I'm assuming this masked the issue at hand because two strings can be compared just as fine with `==` and `Equals`. Try casting your `SelectedItem` to a string and compare then.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel  I tried the exact same code with == and it didn't work. I used Equals and it worked. I don't understand why it worked, but it did

Comment: @user2781018: see my addendum "Try casting your SelectedItem to a string and compare then".

Comment: @user2781018 You called `TrainerFileHandler` a constructor. How is it a constructor?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I originally tried casting it as a string, but I must have messed up because it does work casing it as a string.

Comment: @user2781018: and that is your actual problem ;) It's a lot safer to work with a concrete type rather than `object`, use the cast and (for ease-of-use) `==`.